# French accents not displaying correctly in Chrome under Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, display, language

I use both English and French in my everyday work as a translator, so I don't have any keyboard-related issues. For about two months now, all my accented French letters are displaying incorrectly, to the point where it's hard to read certain texts. This occurs on French-language web pages as well as on Facebook, etc. I tried changing fonts, coding, eliminating apparently corrupted Helvetica fonts, but no joy. Some of the suggestions I've seen on other forums are beyond my IT capabilities, so I need a clear explanation of how to fix this, if anyone has one.

[image]

Comment: I don't have IE on my computer anymore, some fool from Norton took over my machine when I had another problem and deleted it but was unable to reinstall it. Isn't that just marvelous? I assume you mean I should uninstall Chrome then reinstall it in safe mode? Sorry to be so duh.

Comment: I would consider a system restore! Or a repair. I've not known anyone to remove IE - this seems like nonsense (the person at Norton should not have removed it)

Comment: The person at Norton swears that I "must have somehow deleted IE" myself. First of all, deleting IE would never in a million years have occurred to me, and second of all, I SAW the Norton technician dump IE 11 in the trash. I think I'm going to have to see a repairman to fix my accent problem and restore IE 11, which I don't particularly like, but it has its uses.

Comment: I would suspect he only remove the short cut. To test it, click start (windows logo) and type in `iexplore` . When you say the person at Norton, I have to ask (and no offence is meant so please understand I am trying to help :) ) but they didn't start the call with a thick accent explaining "they've detected virus's on your computer"?

Comment: Ha! No, no thick accents from Estonia or Slovakia! No, a real Norton technician who helped me solve a weird problem having to do with my firewall. They were very efficient until they trashed IE.

Comment: Can you try :  Open C:\Users\[Your User Name]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\User StyleSheets  and find the Custom.css and open it with notepad. Add the below codes and save:
`@font-face { font-family: 'helvetica neue'; src: local('Arial'); }
@font-face { font-family: 'helvetica neue'; font-weight:bold; src: local('Arial'); }`

Comment: Also go to Preference > Contents > Fonts > Advanced : Un-check Allow pages to choose their own fonts . You may select a well known font!

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED!!! On a Google forum I found a message in French which explained that corruped HELVETICA fonts were still on my PC, even if I couldn't see them or find them in my list of fonts. He gave me a link to reinstall UNCORRUPTED Helvetica fonts. I downloaded the zip file, extracted the fonts, and inserted them into my list of fonts. Them I emptied my Chrome browser and opened a few of the pages that were causing problems. GONE! Here's the link I used if it can assist anyone else: http://www.2shared.com/file/tIEePIVP/Helvetica.html

Comment: * doing a little happy dance*

Comment: Ah, so my suggestion of changing the font would have worked? I will move that to an aswer, although you can answer your own question (which I suggest you do) :)

Comment: Thank you Dave! I'm sure your solution would have worked as well. I was astounded when I managed to fix this problem. Apparently, corrupted Helvetica fonts are quite prevalent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing there is something wrong with the font. Try using a different font.

Open the following location

```
 C:\Users\Your User Name\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\User StyleSheets
```

Find the Custom.css 
Right click, open with notepad or wordpad or notepad++ or similar. 
Add 2 lines of code, and then save:

```
 @font-face { font-family: 'helvetica neue'; src: local('Arial'); }   
 @font-face { font-family: 'helvetica neue'; font-weight:bold; src: local('Arial'); }
```

Restart Chrome

Answer (score 0):

On a Google forum I found a message in French which explained that corrupted HELVETICA fonts were still on my PC, even if I couldn't see them or find them in my list of fonts.

He gave me a link to reinstall UNCORRUPTED Helvetica fonts. I downloaded the zip file, extracted the fonts, and inserted them into my list of fonts. Them I emptied my Chrome browser and opened a few of the pages that were causing problems. Solved!

Here's the link I used if it can assist anyone else:

[2shared.com/file/tIEePIVP/Helvetica.html](http://2shared.com/file/tIEePIVP/Helvetica.html)

Comment: You can mark your post as answer by clicking the green tick. You can also add upvotes and downvotes .